# Parse an elementTree to return a string in XML form - Python

Tags: python, xml, string, elementtree

is there a way to parse an entire ElementTree from a file and return it as a string in python? I would like to read the entire file into a single string value, for example grabbing the entire output of dump(tree)? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

print "Enter a filename"
filename = input()
tree = ET.parse(filename)
string = tree.tostring() ##is there a way to do something like this?
```

test.xml

```
<data>

     <serial>

     <serial name = "serial">SN001</serial>

     </serial>

     <items>

    <item>Test1 = Failed</item>

    <item>Test2 = Passed</item>

    <item>Test3 = Passed</item>

      </items>

</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tostring` is a module function, not a method.

```
string = ET.tostring(tree.getroot())
```

Comment: I tried something like that earlier and got an error saying that ElementTree has no attribute named 'tag'

Comment: @wheatfairies - Yep, I did, too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent! That was exactly what I needed. Thank you Rob. I will accept your answer when it becomes available.